# R: min, max, mean and median of a vector within 95% confidence interval (2.5 to 97.5 percentiles)

Tags: r, max, mean, percentile, quantile

I ran 1000 iterations to generate a normal deviate using `rnorm` and saved it in a vector:

`rvec <- rnorm (1000, mean = 0.143927671, sd = 0.110680809)`

I need to find a min, max, mean and median of a vector within 95% confidence interval (2.5 to 97.5 percentiles), are there any functions to do that in R?
I was trying to use `apply`, but it doesn't seem to give what I want:

```
rmax = apply(rvec, 2, max, c(.025, 0.975))
```

So I want to estimate min/max/mean/median of a population based on a random sample / subset of that population

In Excel there is an AddIn for MonteCarloanalysis, but I want to do that in R.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by vector?

Comment: Wait, what programming language are you looking for? This could be implemented in many many ways

Comment: I'm really confused as to _why_ one would calculate min/max/mean/median on a vector with less than 100% CI.  100% CI is fast and easy.  95% is complex and slow.

Comment: I ran 1000 iterations to generate a normal deviate using rnorm and saved it in a vector, so now I want to find min, max, mean and median of that. I'm using R.

Comment: Please add the "r" tag to indicate which language you're using. You'll have to delete one of the existing tags.

Comment: @MooingDuck Exactly - min, max, median and mean are all exactly-defined metrics on a data set that don't even entertain the notion of a "confidence interval". Given `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the min is 1, max is 4, mean is 2.5 and median is 2.5... Not sure what OP is really thinking here...

Comment: I ran 1000 iterations to generate a normal deviate using `rnorm` and saved it in a vector: 

`rvec <- rnorm (1000, mean = 0.143927671, sd = 0.110680809)`
, which gave me a random sample from a normal distribution.
I need to find a min, max, mean and median of that within 95% confidence interval (2.5 to 97.5 percentiles)
I was trying to use `apply`, but it doesn't seem to give what I want:

    rmax = apply(rvec, 2, max, c(.025, 0.975)) In Excel there is an AddIn for MonteCarloanalysis, but I want to do that in R.

Comment: @Liza Ah... So you want to *estimate* min/max/mean/median of a *population* based on a random *sample* / *subset* of that population? If so, that certainly isn't clear from the way you worded your question...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Sorry, took me a while to figure out how to put that in words.

Comment: In a normally distributed population, there is not really a min or max -- i.e., the tails of the normal curve never actually reach zero. So, how would you estimate min/max of a population?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get a confidence interval for the median based on a sample S would be to take bootstrap resamples of S, computing the median of each sample. Let's take your example (setting the random seed for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(100)
rvec <- rnorm (1000, mean = 0.143927671, sd = 0.110680809)
samp.medians <- replicate(500, median(sample(rvec, length(rvec), replace=T)))
summary(samp.medians)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  0.1327  0.1425  0.1480  0.1473  0.1505  0.1615 
quantile(samp.medians, c(0.025, 0.975))
#      2.5%     97.5% 
# 0.1377611 0.1574934
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate concept which the confidence interval around the likely quantile that the current estimate represents.  For example, if you take the median of 10 samples, that *is* an estimate of the 50th percentile of the distribution, but it is an *estimate* so there is some error.  To get the range of the quantiles that your estimate represents, you can use binom.test  as in

```
binom.test(x=sum(rvec>median(rvec)),n=length(rvec),conf.level=0.95)
#> [some text omitted from the output of binom.test]
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.4685492 0.5314508
```

which indicates that `median(rvec)` is likely within the 46.9th percentile and 53.1th percentile of the underlying distribution, with 95% confidence.

Note that bootstrapping will give you a range for which the  true median of the underlying distribution is likely to fall within, but it isn't valid for biased estimates like 'min' an 'max', for which the the empirical estimates (`max(rvec)`, for example) are biased.  However, the above method will give you the confidence intervals for the percentiles of the distribution that your favorite statistic (min/max/median/mean, 75th percentile, etc) are likely to fall within.